# how to list a private dependency with the latest tag in npm?

Tags: npm

adding a private repo can be cone via

```
"devDependencies": {
  "my-foo-bar": "git+ssh://git@ssh.foobar.com:foo/bar.git"
}
```

How can I now tell npm to always install the latest available tag?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as there are tags in the pointed repo, above example does exactly that: Pulling the highest tag-number